# Почему некоторые вопросы показаны неярким шрифтом?

Tags: поддержка

Почему некоторые вопросы показаны неярким шрифтом?
[Пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNXTX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего одну или обе метки вопроса  вы добавили в список игнорируемых. В этом случае вопросы с игнорируемыми метками или  затемняются, или не показываются вовсе (в зависимости от вашего выбора).